# Add a bot using a bot discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I wanted to know if it was possible if you could use a bot to add another bot to the current server. Of course the bot would need permissions in the server, but is it possible? Is there a certain code that could be used?

Comment: That is not possible.

Comment: technically, but only in a way that breaks tos(terms of service)

Comment: It is not possible to do this without using self-bots (which are not allowed by Discord's terms of service, as mentioned by The Bomb Squad).

Answer (score 2):

Discord Bots are similar to user accounts in quiet a lot of ways however, bots cannot add other bots to a server.

This is mainly due to security and the fact that Discord wants the server admins to have full control over the server.